# Trying to delete all installed files on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I want to delete all the packages installed when I ran

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

which is the only thing I installed so far (alongside numpy). I tried using

```
pip3 uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

But for every single package in pip3 list I get a statement as such:

**Found existing installation attrs 19.3.0**

**Not uninstalling attrs at /ur/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr**

**Can't uninstall 'attrs'. No files were found to uninstall.**

This is on a Windows OS using the Windows Subsystem for linux and Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Can't seem to find a solution online that doesn't display the bold text above :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a better fit for askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an `apt-get remove <package_name>` OR an `apt-get purge <package_name>`.

**remove** will uninstall the binaries and can be executed like so:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

**purge** will uninstall the binaries and remove any related cruft like config files that were created as a part of the installation. You can execute like so:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-pip
```

If you installed libraries specifically via `pip3 install` and wanted to delete everything you've installed via pip3, you can do:

```
for x in $(pip3 list | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '^(Package|[-]+)'); do echo "${x}"; done
```